# Incrementing an argument and recursion

Tags: c, recursion, increment

```
void base_aux(unsigned int n, unsigned int base, unsigned int x) {
    if (n > (base - 1)) {
        printf("%u", n % base);
        base_aux(n / base, base, x++);
    } else {
        printf("%u", n);
        zero_int(32 - x);
        printf("\n %d \n", x);
    }
}
```

So, I'm trying to see why my `x` isn't incrementing. It stays at zero when I call `zero_int`. Any reason why? How do I fix this?

Comment: See what happens if you change `x++` to `++x`

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
foo(x++);
```

it is equivalent to

```
temp = x;
x = x + 1;
foo(temp);
```

So you can say that `x++` returns `x` and then increments `x`. It is called postfix increment.

So in your code you keep call the function with the same value of `x`

If you do

```
foo(++x);
```

it is equivalent to

```
x = x + 1;
temp = x;
foo(temp);
```

So you can say that `++x` increments `x` and then returns `x`. It is called prefix increment.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `++x`, with `x++` the value of `x` is passed into the recursive call without increment, then incremented within the scope of caller method, thus you will have same `x` value for all recursion cases.

The location of `++` determines the timing of increment, and in your case it should be before it is evaluated in the method call.

[More on this topic.](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4410601/Pre-increment-or-post-increment-in-C-C-)

Answer (score -1):

Your x is not being increased because you try increment it in as argument to the function. First increase x and then pass it to the function. It may solve your problem.

```
       void base_aux(unsigned int n, unsigned int base, unsigned int x) {
if (n > (base - 1)) {
    printf("%u", n % base);
    x=x+1;
    base_aux(n / base, base, x);
} else {
    printf("%u", n);
    zero_int(32 - x);
    printf("\n %d \n", x);
}
```